# Array aleatorio de tamaño dinamico en C++

Tags: c++, array, random

Me podrían dar una ayuda de cómo crear un array con dígitos aleatorios, y que sea el usuario el que defina el tamaño del array (la cantidad de dígitos).

Sé crearlo pero de manera estática definiéndole el tamaño en la declaración del array.

Lo que tengo es algo así:

```
int a[] = {16, 2, 77, 40, 12071};
int n, result=0;

int main ()
{
  for ( n=0 ; n<5 ; ++n )
  {
    result += a[n];
  }
  cout << result;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Muéstranos cómo lo creas de manera estática... es un comienzo que demuestra buena voluntad en tu pregunta.

Comment: @eferion por supuesto, ya modifique la publicación

Comment: Ok, viendo el código te informo que hay una respuesta muy similar ya contestada. Te aconsejo que le eches un vistazo puesto que tu duda ya fue resuelta.

Comment: @eferion no sabia que estaba duplicadam revisare el link. Gracais

Comment: ¿Es para un trabajo de clase?

Comment: @nergeia Hola buenos dias. No estoy estudiando C++ por mi cuenta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

bueno no se si mi respuesta te sirva pero:

1.- Datos aleatorios: existe una una funcion llamada srand, creo que podrias llenar las casillas del arreglo con esa funcion

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL)); 
    int d=rand()%12; //rango hasta el 12, si quieres puedes cambiarle  
    cout<<d;
}
```

2.- El tamaño dinamico podrias pedir que se ingrese por ej:

```
int x;
cout<<"Ingrese el tamaño del arreglo: ";
cin>>x;
cout<<"\n\n";
//y despues declaras el arreglo
int [x];
//y ahi implementas los for
```

Y ahi puedes ir asignado valores al arreglo.

Comment: Perfecto muchas gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo que haría sería definir una variable tipo int estática para pedir el tamaño a los usuarios, luego, para crear el propio array dinámico haría un `int* array = new int [tamaño]` y ya estarías trabajando con memoria dinámica aunque te recomiendo que te mires las STLs  y  de C++ que trabajan con memoria dinámica son bastantes fáciles de usar y además te abstraen bastante de tener que usar punteros que todos sabemos que siempre hay problemillas. Después para los números aleatorios puedes coger una de las funciones que hay para ello y la aplicas fácilmente. `rand()` por ejemplo.

Saludos y suerte.